# Problem related to c type casting differnce in two situation and compiler error

Tags: c

I am on os project there i got many files in one code was

```
#define ELFHDR      ((struct Elf *) 0x10000)
void readseg(uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t);
readseg((uint32_t) ELFHDR, SECTSIZE*8, 0);
```

The error was related to `ELFHDR` being a `struct *` than casting it to be `uint32_t`.

When compiling everyone together i get no error.
But but i compile this file alone it give  `-Wpointer-to-int-cast`
Why it not gives error there but when compiling it alone it gives error.

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size   [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
```

Comment: The make file use different compile options that compiling the file on its own?

Comment: But than what option tell compiler to compile it without giving any casting error

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the address is aligned and valid memory, you can convert from an integer to any object pointer type with a cast. But if you do the other way around, the integer type you convert to needs to be large enough to contain an integer representation of a pointer.

In your case `uint32_t` is not a suitable type. You should have used `uintptr_t` instead, which is a type existing solely for the purpose of expressing a pointer as integer.

Comment: In a 64 bit system pointer may not fit into 32 bit integers and the compiler warns due to this.

Comment: @Gerhard yes you said right. I totally not remembered that os was of 32 bit and i was compiling it on 64 bit without giving any 32bit option to compiler

Comment: @Gerhard the problem was i not used -m32 on 64 bit system for 32 bit system file.Thanks for helping